# How to fix android...ViewPager in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs, mobile-application, android-appbarlayout

I currently making a messaging app for my school project. I'm just starting mobile development this semester. Currently have run into a problem where when I add android ViewPager my activity_main.xml shows:

On the preview of the activity_main.xml
android...ViewPager (in blacktext in grey brackground)

For further explanation:

Anyway I was just thinking of following along to a tutorial because i'm stiil not that capable enough to code but are proffessor still told us to make an app even though his not really teaching that much. That's why i dont understand anything at all.

I just went to this tutorial and decided to use it for my whole project since i dont know anything at all.

So I went and watch and followed along a playlist on how to make a messaging app on this youtube channel Coding cafe, this is currently the video I'm watching and following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Am-iad_Gkg&index=5&list=PLxefhmF0pcPmtdoud8f64EpgapkclCllj

First Project:

The first few tutorials everything was fine but at video number 5
Ive' watch the whole video did everything he did but after running the app if you see on his video the tabs were working on his but not on mine I just saw the title of my app but the tabs were not showing at all.

I tried looking at my work then i saw my xml file and there goes the:

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0hAT.png)
On the preview of the activity_main.xml
android...ViewPager (in blacktext in grey brackground)

I didn't know what to do because i was stupid did not know what to search, I search android...ViewPager, viewpager in android studio not working but all i was getting was "how to make a appbartab" and other tutorials on how to make one but i was afraid since this project is due february I' really rushing.

New Project Redo:
Back to the problem so after that i did not know what to do so I went and redo the project. Followed his tutorial again then I noticed that my problem was in the viewpager itself in the xml file.

When I typed the:

android View pagerin my activity_main.xml

It showed this again:
On the preview of the activity_main.xml
android...ViewPager (in blacktext in grey brackground)

so I was like what do i need to do?

So in the "First Project:" I already finished coding and doing everything he did in the video really carefully and as said it did not work

In "New Project Redo:" my progress is up until this point (timestamp 3:16)

I was afraid of going further because this code (see it on the video timestamp 3:16)

Made my activity_main preview do this:
On the preview of the activity_main.xml
android...ViewPager (in blacktext in grey brackground)

I dont know what the problem is so I really need help.

This is my code, as i've said havent add the fragment or anything yet cause i redid the project my progress is still in video 5 (timestamp 3:16).

Refer to the video for more information some people also have this problem in the comments but there are no replies.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Am-iad_Gkg&index=5&list=PLxefhmF0pcPmtdoud8f64EpgapkclCllj

If anyone can help me then thank very much.

```
     My activity_main.xml
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout">
    </include>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_tabs_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>

MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Toolbar mToolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chatterfly");
    }
}

app_bar_layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I expect to have my app have an actual app bar where which has chats groups and contacts in it. Which right now isnt showing up when I run the app it only shows the Title of my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tab into your tab layout in order to show tab there by doing somehting like this `tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(title));`

As reference you can also look at [this](https://github.com/pramonow/androidbasic/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pramonow/com/androidbasic/activity/ViewPagerActivity.java) code, you can ignore the fragment adapter add the moment if you don't need it at the moment.